# Whats wrong with the ActiveSupport with Rails 3.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

When I start rails 3.2.1 myapp with unicorn, following kind of errors/exceptions always get logged. Googled and tried to resolve it, but couldn't fix it.

```
==> log/unicorn_err.log <==
Exception `NameError' at
 /myapp/releases/c2c1e8f50b31eede21692692cf6dac28a
 d85177e/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/act
 ive_support/core_ext/module/remove_method.rb:4 - method `_routes'
  not defined in Class
Exception `NameError' at
 /myapp/releases/c2c1e8f50b31eede21692692cf6dac28a
 d85177e/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/act
 ive_support/core_ext/module/remove_method.rb:4 - method `helpers'
  not defined in Class
```

And there are other lots of `NameError'` errors like in this someone other's gist https://gist.github.com/1353923